# perl-how to treat a string as a binary number?

Tags: perl

Read a file that contains an address and a data, like below:

```
@0, 12345678
@1, 5a5a5a5a
...
```

My aim is to read the address and the data. Consider the data I read is in hex format, and then I need to unpack them to binary number. 
So `12345678` would become `00010010001101000101011001111000`
Then, I need to further unpack the transferred binary number to another level.
So it becomes, 
`00000000000000010000000000010000000000000001000100000001000000000000000100000001000000010001000000000001000100010001000000000000`

They way I did is like below

```
while(<STDIN>) {
 if (/\@(\S+)\s+(\S+)/) {
    $addr = $1;
    $data = $2;
    $mem{$addr} = ${data};
 } 
}

foreach $key (sort {$a <=> $b} (keys %mem)) {

  my $str = unpack ('B*', pack ('H*',$mem{$key}));
  my $str2 = unpack ('B*', pack ('H*', $str));
  printf ("@%x ", $key);
  printf ("%s",$str2);
  printf ("\n"); 
}
```

It works, however, my next step is to do some numeric operation on the transferred bits. 
Such as bitwise or and shifting. I tried << and | operator, both are for numbers, not strings. So I don't know how to solve this.

Please leave your comments if you have better ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Do the arithmetic first, then convert to a string of ones and zeros.

Comment: tripleee: I want to do a shift on the final 256bits binary numbers, l don't know how to do that first.

Comment: Yes, on the actual numbers, not on their string representation. Instead of "unpack; unpack; shift" do "unpack; shift; unpack".

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @tripleee You can't simply do arithmetic on 256 bit numbers, without using some `bigint` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ [Bit::Vector](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Bit-Vector/Vector.pod) module from metaCPAN

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bit::Vector;

my $str = "1111000011011001010101000111001100010000001111001010101000111010001011";
printf "orig str: %72s\n", $str;

#only 72 bits for better view
my $vec = Bit::Vector->new_Bin(72,$str);
printf "vec     : %72s\n", $vec->to_Bin();

$vec->Move_Left(2); 
printf "left 2  : %72s\n", $vec->to_Bin();

$vec->Move_Right(4); 
printf "right 4 : %72s\n", $vec->to_Bin();
```

prints:

```
orig str:   1111000011011001010101000111001100010000001111001010101000111010001011
vec     : 001111000011011001010101000111001100010000001111001010101000111010001011
left 2  : 111100001101100101010100011100110001000000111100101010100011101000101100
right 4 : 000011110000110110010101010001110011000100000011110010101010001110100010
```

If you need do some math with arbitrary precision, you can also use [Math::BigInt](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigInt) or `use bigint` (http://perldoc.perl.org/bigint.html)

Answer (score 2):

Hex and binary are *text* representation of numbers. Shifting and bit manipulations are *numerical* operations. You want a number, not text.

```
my $hex = '5a5a5a5a';
$num = hex($hex);               # Convert to number.
$num >>= 1;                     # Manipulate the number.
$hex = sprintf('%08X', $num);   # Convert back to hex.
```

In a comment, you mention you want to deal with 256 bit numbers. The native numbers don't support that, but you can use Math::BigInt.

Comment: Could you add please some example of shifting (left-right) for 96bit (12byte) number with Math::BigInt e.g. the result should be 96bit too?

Comment: @kobame, You can use `<<` and `&` just as you would normally.

Comment: The `$b <<= 1` and `$b & $mask` are OK. But how to print out the null padded binary string to be exaclty 96 characters long from `$b->as_bin()`?

Comment: @kobame, `sprintf('%096s', substr($num->as_bin(), 2))`

Comment: Thank you. Now got it - need to use the `substr` with the shifted amount.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution of this is forget about treat them as numbers, just treat them as string . I use substring and string concentration instead of shift. Then for the or operation , I just add each bit of the string, if it's 0 the result is 0, else is 1.

It may not be the best way to solve this problem. But that's the way I finally used.